# reporting services - Page break within a cell

Tags: reporting-services

On an application, multiple users can give feedback about an event. A Feedback is composed by the username, date and details.

The application also provides a report with an header and the list of feedbacks on that event. This list is a table, without header or footer, but with 2 rows for each feedback. One row containing the username and date and the other with the feedback details just like the example below:

> username - date
>
> several lines of feedback details

Everything works great until someone decided to submit a feedback with 25 lines. Since the cell is to big to fit on that page, reporting services will move that cell to the next page but keeps the cell with the username and data on the first page.

Is there a way to split the details cell between the 2 pages, or at least keep both rows together?

I'm using report server 2005 for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up placing each row on a subreport. I don't have access to the source code anymore but I think that the report services keep subreports together or at least there was a property that would keep the subreports together.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `KeepTogether` property of the details textbox to `False`.

This might start splitting lot of comments though, which if you have a RowGroup for the comment you might be able to fix by setting the `KeepTogether`  for the RowGroup as `True`.

Comment: I'm using reporting services 2005. I don't have the KeepTogether property

Comment: I understand there is a table level KeepTogether. Does that help?